# Dynamically counting frequency of element in a array in PHP

Tags: php, python

I have an array say:

```
$array = array(1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1)
```

I want to convert this array and having the value as the key and its frequency as the value
output should be like:

```
$array = array (
         "1" => 2,
         "2" => 1,
         "3" => 2,
         "4" => 1,
         "5" => 2
)
```

I know how to do this in python. But I have to do it in PHP. I have implemented this in python with follwoing code:
python code:

```
d = {}
for j in tweets: // tweet is a array of integers as given above $array
d[j] = d.get(j, 0) + 1 // This will make a dictionary with the values in the array as key and its frequency as value of the dictionary .. Get() dynamically increase the value
```

Please help.

Comment: `array_count_values` only in PHP

Comment: Just to note your Python solution could use a `collections.defaultdict` or use `d.setdefault(j, 0) += 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
$newArray = array_count_values( $array );
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.org/n35PZ26I

---

To then sort it by its keys, use `ksort`:

```
ksort( $newArray );
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.org/ZN0zHn4S

Comment: That was Ninja Edit ... where did your first loop go  ?

Comment: Is there any function that php doesn't have?

Comment: output should be sorted.. by keys values

Comment: would you like coffee with that too sir?